# How do I get multiple Java threads to pause and resume at a user's request?

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx, synchronization, scenebuilder

I'm creating a 20-minute countdown timer application. I'm using JavaFX SceneBuilder to do this. The timer is composed of two labels (one for minutes, one for seconds--each composed of a `CountdownTimer` class object), and a progress bar (the timer looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ddve.png)). Each of these components are separate and running on separate threads concurrently to prevent the UI from freezing up. And it works.

**The problem:**

The three threads (`minutesThread`, `secondsThread`, `progressBarUpdaterThread`) I need to be able to pause and resume are regular .java classes. When the user clicks the play (start) button, the click signals the `FXMLDocumentController` (the class that controls how the components in the UI are updated) method `startTimer()` to do work regarding the timer.

Right now the only functionality `startTimer()` in `FXMLDocumentController` has is: user clicks play (start) button --> timer begins counting down.

I want the user to be able to pause and resume the timer with this same button. I've tried using synchronization across the `FXMLDocumentController` class and the other three threads to no avail in multiple different ways (admittedly, I have almost no experience coding for concurrency). I just want to be able to pause and play the timer!

Can anyone offer me advice in how to go about this? Thanks in advance.

**startTimer() in FXMLDocumentController.java (used to start the countdown timer):**

```
@FXML
void startTimer(MouseEvent event) throws FileNotFoundException {
    // update click count so user can switch between pause and start
    startTimerButtonClickCount++;

    // create a pause button image to replace the start button image when the user pauses the timer
    Image pauseTimerButtonImage = new Image(new 
         FileInputStream("/Users/Home/NetBeansProjects/Take20/src/Images/pause2_black_18dp.png"));
    // setting imageview to be used when user clicks on start button to pause it
    ImageView pauseTimerButtonImageView = new ImageView(pauseTimerButtonImage);
    // setting the width and height of the pause image
    pauseTimerButtonImageView.setFitHeight(31);
    pauseTimerButtonImageView.setFitWidth(28);
    // preserving the pause image ratio after resize
    pauseTimerButtonImageView.setPreserveRatio(true);

    // create a start button image to replace the pause button image when the user unpauses the timer
    Image startTimerButtonImage = new Image(new 
          FileInputStream("/Users/Home/NetBeansProjects/
          Take20/src/Images/play_arrow2_black_18dp.png"));
    ImageView startTimerButtonImageView = new ImageView(startTimerButtonImage);
    startTimerButtonImageView.setFitHeight(31);
    startTimerButtonImageView.setFitWidth(28);
    startTimerButtonImageView.setPreserveRatio(true);

    // progressBar updater
    ProgressBarUpdater progressBarUpdater = new ProgressBarUpdater();
    TimerThread progressBarThread = new TimerThread(progressBarUpdater);
    // minutes timer
    CountdownTimer minutesTimer = new CountdownTimer(19);
    TimerThread minutesThread = new TimerThread(minutesTimer);
    // seconds timer
    CountdownTimer secondsTimer = new CountdownTimer(59);
    TimerThread secondsThread = new TimerThread(secondsTimer);

    // bind our components in order to update them
    progressBar.progressProperty().bind(progressBarUpdater.progressProperty());
    minutesTimerLabel.textProperty().bind(minutesTimer.messageProperty());
    secondsTimerLabel.textProperty().bind(secondsTimer.messageProperty());

    // start the threads in order to have them run parallel when the start button is clicked
    progressBarThread.start();
    minutesThread.start();
    secondsThread.start();

    // if the start button was clicked, then we set its graphic to the pause image
    // if the button click count is divisible by 2, we pause it, otherwise, we play it (and change 
    // the button images accordingly).
    if (startTimerButtonClickCount % 2 == 0) {
        startTimerButton.setGraphic(pauseTimerButtonImageView);
        progressBarThread.pauseThread();
        minutesThread.pauseThread();
        secondsThread.pauseThread();

        progressBarThread.run();
        minutesThread.run();
        secondsThread.run();
    } else {
        startTimerButton.setGraphic(startTimerButtonImageView);
        progressBarThread.resumeThread();
        minutesThread.resumeThread();
        secondsThread.resumeThread();

        progressBarThread.run();
        minutesThread.run();
        secondsThread.run();
    }
}
```

**TimerThread (used to suspend/resume timer threads when user clicks the play/pause button in the UI):**

```
public class TimerThread extends Thread implements Runnable {

public boolean paused = false;
public final Task<Integer> timerObject;
public final Thread thread;

public TimerThread(Task timerObject) {
    this.timerObject = timerObject;
    this.thread = new Thread(timerObject);
}

@Override
public void start() {
    this.thread.start();
    System.out.println("TimerThread started");
}

@Override
public void run() {
    System.out.println("TimerThread class run() called");
    try {
        synchronized (this.thread) {
            System.out.println("synchronized called");
            while (paused) {
                System.out.println("wait called");
                this.thread.wait();
                System.out.println("waiting...");
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("exception caught in TimerThread");
    }

}

synchronized void pauseThread() {
    paused = true;
}

synchronized void resumeThread() {
    paused = false;
    notify();
}
}
```

**CountdownTimer.java (used to create and update the minutes and seconds of the countdown timer):**

```
public class CountdownTimer extends Task<Integer> {

private int time;
private Timer timer;
private int timerDelay;
private int timerPeriod;
private int repetitions;

public CountdownTimer(int time) {
    this.time = time;
    this.timer = new Timer();
    this.repetitions = 1;
}

@Override
protected Integer call() throws Exception {
    // we will create a new thread for each time unit (minutes, seconds)
    // we start with whatever time is passed to the constructor
    // we have threads devoted to each case so both minutes and second cases can run parallel to each other.
    switch (time) {
        // for our minutes timer
        case 19:
            // first display should be 19 first since our starting timer time should be 19:59 
            updateMessage("19");

            // set delay and period to change every minute of the countdown
            // 60,000 milliseconds in one minute
            timerDelay = 60000;
            timerPeriod = 60000;
            System.out.println("Running minutesthread....");

            // use a timertask to loop through time at a fixed rate as set by timerDelay, until the timer reaches 0 and is cancelled
            timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    //check if the flag is divisible by 2, then we sleep this thread 

                    // if time reaches 0, we want to update the minute label to 00
                    if (time == 0) {
                        updateMessage("0" + Integer.toString(time));
                        timer.cancel();
                        timer.purge();
                        // if the time is a single digit, append a 0 and reduce time by 1
                    } else if (time <= 10) {
                        --time;
                        updateMessage("0" + Integer.toString(time));
                        // otherwise, we we default to reducing time by 1, every minute
                    } else {
                        --time;
                        updateMessage(Integer.toString(time));
                    }
                }
            }, timerDelay, timerPeriod);
            // exit switch statement once we finish our work 
            break;

        // for our seconds timer
        case 59:
            // first display 59 first since our starting timer time should be 19:59 
            updateMessage("59");
            // use a counter to count repetitions so we can cancel the timer when it arrives at 0, after 20 repetitions

            // set delay and period to change every second of the countdown
            // 1000 milliseconds in one second
            timerDelay = 1000;
            timerPeriod = 1000;
            System.out.println("Running seconds thread....");

            // use a timertask to loop through time at a fixed rate as set by timerDelay, until the timer reaches 0 and is cancelled
            timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    --time;
                    System.out.println("repititions: " + repetitions);
                    // Use a counter to count repetitions so we can cancel the timer when it arrives at 0, after 1200 repetitions
                    // We will reach 1200 repetitions at the same time as the time variable reaches 0, since the timer 
                    // loops/counts down every second (1000ms).
                    // 1200 seconds = 20 minutes * 60 seconds (1 minute)
                    repetitions++;

                    if (time == 0) {
                        if (repetitions == 1200) {
                            // reset repetitions if user decides to click play again
                            repetitions = 0;
                            timer.cancel();
                            System.out.println("repetitions ran");
                        }
                        updateMessage("0" + Integer.toString(time));
                        // reset timer to 60, so it will countdown again from 60 after reaching 0 (since we have to repeat the seconds timer multiple times,
                        // unlike the minutes timer, which only needs to run once
                        time = 60;
                        System.out.println("time == 00 ran");
                    } else if (time < 10 && time > 0) {
                        updateMessage("0" + Integer.toString(time));
                    } else {
                        updateMessage(Integer.toString(time));
                    }
                }
            }, timerDelay, timerPeriod);
            // exit switch statement once we finish our work
            break;
    }

    return null;
}
}
```

**ProgressBarUpdater.java (used to update the progress bar as the countdown timer counts down):**

```
public class ProgressBarUpdater extends Task<Integer> {

private int progressBarPeriod;
private Timer timer;
private double time;

public ProgressBarUpdater() {
    this.timer = new Timer();
    this.time = 1200000;
}

@Override
protected Integer call() throws Exception {
    progressBarPeriod = 10;
    System.out.println("Running progressBar thread....");

    // using a timer task, we update our progressBar by reducing the filled progressBar every 9.68 milliseconds 
    // (instead of 10s to account for any delay in program runtime) to ensure that the progressBar ends at the same time our timer reaches 0. 
    // according to its max (1200000ms or 20 minutes)
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            time -= 9.68;
            updateProgress(time, 1200000);
            System.out.println("progressBarUpdater is running");
        }
    }, 0, progressBarPeriod);

    return null;
}

@Override
protected void updateProgress(double workDone, double maxTime) {
    super.updateProgress(workDone, maxTime);
}

}
```

Comment: Using a background thread for this, let alone multiple background threads, is only going to make it harder. Consider using the [animation API](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/14/javafx.graphics/javafx/animation/package-summary.html) instead. Check out [JavaFX periodic background task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9966136/). Personally, I would use an `AnimationTimer` for this but you could also try `Timeline` or `PauseTransition`.

Comment: You're basically updating the same data 3 times from seperate threads. This shouldn't be done especially since computing the value from a single number is trivial/fast. Furthermore `TimerTask` is weird: You extend `Thread` but override `start` in a way that removes the core functionality of a `Thread` object; instead you delegate to another `Thread` object; why extend `Thread`, if you're not using any functionality of the `Thread` class for that object?

Comment: don't get why you want 3 threads for counting down time? It's the same time left, visualized with 3 views .. so you can use one task, listen to its output and update the views (or do it the other way round and use fx animation api, as suggested by @Slaw)

Comment: As others have suggested, this is way too convoluted for what you're trying to achieve. Don't separate the minutes and seconds; these are essentially the same data. Use either a single `int` to represent total seconds remaining, or a `java.time.Duration`. I would approach this without threads at all: your timer is essentially in one of three states (use an enum): running, paused, or finished. You can represent the time of the timer by methods `getTimeRemaining()` and `getEndTime()`, and compute those on the fly depending on the state. Then use, e.g., an `AnimationTimer` for displaying it.

Comment: @Slaw Where would I be writing the code for this AnimationTimer? Do I write the code in FXMLDocumentController? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

As I mentioned in a comment, using a background thread for this, let alone *three(!)* background threads, will only make this harder to implement and reason about. It would be better to use the [animation API](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/14/javafx.graphics/javafx/animation/package-summary.html) provided by JavaFX—it's asynchronous but still executes on the *JavaFX Application Thread*.  And as mentioned by others, you only need one value to represent the time remaining and another value representing the duration. From there you can display the minutes, seconds, and progress.

Personally, I would use an [`AnimationTimer`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/14/javafx.graphics/javafx/animation/AnimationTimer.html) as it gives you the timestamp of the current frame which you can use to calculate how much time is left. To make things easier to use I would also wrap the `AnimationTimer` in another class and have that latter class expose an API more appropriate for countdown timers. For example:

```java
package com.example;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import javafx.animation.AnimationTimer;
import javafx.beans.property.LongProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyDoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyDoubleWrapper;
import javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyLongProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyLongWrapper;
import javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyObjectWrapper;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleLongProperty;

public class CountdownTimer {

  private static long toMillis(long nanos) {
    return TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.toMillis(nanos);
  }

  /* *********************************************************************
   *                                                                     *
   * Instance Fields                                                     *
   *                                                                     *
   ***********************************************************************/

  private final Timer timer = new Timer();
  private long cachedDuration;

  /* *********************************************************************
   *                                                                     *
   * Constructors                                                        *
   *                                                                     *
   ***********************************************************************/

  public CountdownTimer() {}

  public CountdownTimer(long duration) {
    setDuration(duration);
  }

  /* *********************************************************************
   *                                                                     *
   * Public API                                                          *
   *                                                                     *
   ***********************************************************************/

  public void start() {
    if (getStatus() == Status.READY || getStatus() == Status.PAUSED) {
      timer.start();
      setStatus(Status.RUNNING);
    }
  }

  public void pause() {
    if (getStatus() == Status.RUNNING) {
      timer.pause();
      setStatus(Status.PAUSED);
    }
  }

  public void stopAndReset() {
    timer.stopAndReset();
    setStatus(Status.READY);
  }

  /* *********************************************************************
   *                                                                     *
   * Properties                                                          *
   *                                                                     *
   ***********************************************************************/

  private final ReadOnlyObjectWrapper<Status> status = new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper<>(this, "status", Status.READY) {
    @Override protected void invalidated() {
      if (get() == Status.READY) {
        cachedDuration = Math.abs(getDuration());
        setTimeRemaining(cachedDuration);
      }
    }
  };
  private void setStatus(Status status) { this.status.set(status); }
  public final Status getStatus() { return status.get(); }
  public final ReadOnlyObjectProperty<Status> statusProperty() { return status.getReadOnlyProperty(); }

  private final LongProperty duration = new SimpleLongProperty(this, "duration") {
    @Override protected void invalidated() {
      if (getStatus() == Status.READY) {
        cachedDuration = Math.abs(get());
        setTimeRemaining(cachedDuration);
      }
    }
  };
  public final void setDuration(long duration) { this.duration.set(duration); }
  public final long getDuration() { return duration.get(); }
  public final LongProperty durationProperty() { return duration; }

  private final ReadOnlyLongWrapper timeRemaining = new ReadOnlyLongWrapper(this, "timeRemaining") {
    @Override protected void invalidated() {
      setProgress((double) (cachedDuration - get()) / (double) cachedDuration);
    }
  };
  private void setTimeRemaining(long timeRemaining) { this.timeRemaining.set(timeRemaining); }
  public final long getTimeRemaining() { return timeRemaining.get(); }
  public final ReadOnlyLongProperty timeRemainingProperty() { return timeRemaining.getReadOnlyProperty(); }

  private final ReadOnlyDoubleWrapper progress = new ReadOnlyDoubleWrapper(this, "progress");
  private void setProgress(double progress) { this.progress.set(progress); }
  public final double getProgress() { return progress.get(); }
  public final ReadOnlyDoubleProperty progressProperty() { return progress.getReadOnlyProperty(); }

  /* *********************************************************************
   *                                                                     *
   * Static Classes                                                      *
   *                                                                     *
   ***********************************************************************/

  public enum Status {
    READY,
    RUNNING,
    PAUSED,
    FINISHED
  }

  /* *********************************************************************
   *                                                                     *
   * Classes                                                             *
   *                                                                     *
   ***********************************************************************/

  private class Timer extends AnimationTimer {

    private long triggerTime = Long.MIN_VALUE;
    private long pauseTime = Long.MIN_VALUE;
    private boolean pausing;

    @Override
    public void handle(long now) {
      if (pausing) {
        pauseTime = toMillis(now);
        pausing = false;
        stop();
      } else {
        if (triggerTime == Long.MIN_VALUE) {
          triggerTime = toMillis(now) + cachedDuration;
        } else if (pauseTime != Long.MIN_VALUE) {
          triggerTime += toMillis(now) - pauseTime;
          pauseTime = Long.MIN_VALUE;
        }

        long timeRemaining = Math.max(0, triggerTime - toMillis(now));
        setTimeRemaining(timeRemaining);
        if (timeRemaining == 0) {
          setStatus(Status.FINISHED);
          stop();
        }
      }
    }

    @Override
    public void start() {
      pausing = false;
      super.start();
    }

    void pause() {
      if (triggerTime != Long.MIN_VALUE) {
        pausing = true;
      } else {
        stop();
      }
    }

    void stopAndReset() {
      stop();
      triggerTime = Long.MIN_VALUE;
      pauseTime = Long.MIN_VALUE;
      pausing = false;
    }
  }
}
```

<sup>***Warning:** While the `AnimationTimer` is running the `CountdownTimer` instance cannot be garbage collected.*</sup>

This implementation interprets both the duration and time remaining values as milliseconds. Also, changing the duration after starting the timer has no effect until after the timer is reset (i.e. calling `stopAndReset()`).

---

Here's an example of using the above `CountdownTimer` in an FXML-based application. Note that the example uses distinct buttons for starting, pausing, resuming, and resetting the timer. This is different than what you described in your question but you should be able to rework things to fit your needs. Also, the example provides a way to toggle whether or not the millisecond of the current second is shown.

App.fxml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ProgressBar?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ToolBar?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Separator?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox?>
<?import com.example.CountdownTimer?>
<?import com.example.CountdownTimer.Status?>

<VBox xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/14.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"
      fx:controller="com.example.Controller" prefHeight="300" prefWidth="500">

  <fx:define>
    <!-- 90,000ms == 1m 30s -->
    <CountdownTimer fx:id="timer" duration="90000"/>
    <CountdownTimer.Status fx:id="READY" fx:value="READY"/>
    <CountdownTimer.Status fx:id="RUNNING" fx:value="RUNNING"/>
    <CountdownTimer.Status fx:id="PAUSED" fx:value="PAUSED"/>
  </fx:define>

  <ToolBar style="-fx-font: 10pt 'Monospaced';">
    <Button text="Start" disable="${timer.status != READY}" focusTraversable="false"
            onAction="#handleStartOrResumeTimer"/>
    <Button text="Resume" disable="${timer.status != PAUSED}" focusTraversable="false"
            onAction="#handleStartOrResumeTimer"/>
    <Button text="Pause" disable="${timer.status != RUNNING}" focusTraversable="false" onAction="#handlePauseTimer"/>
    <Button text="Reset" disable="${timer.status == READY || timer.status == RUNNING}" focusTraversable="false"
            onAction="#handleResetTimer"/>
    <Separator/>
    <CheckBox fx:id="showMillisBox" text="Show Millis" focusTraversable="false"/>
  </ToolBar>

  <ProgressBar progress="${timer.progress}" maxWidth="Infinity"/>

  <StackPane VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
    <Label fx:id="timerLabel" style="-fx-font: bold 48pt 'Monospaced';"/>
  </StackPane>
</VBox>
```

Controller.java:

```java
package com.example;

import java.time.Duration;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;

public class Controller {

  @FXML private CountdownTimer timer;
  @FXML private CheckBox showMillisBox;
  @FXML private Label timerLabel;

  @FXML
  private void initialize() {
    timerLabel
        .textProperty()
        .bind(
            Bindings.createStringBinding(
                this::formatTimeRemaining,
                timer.timeRemainingProperty(),
                showMillisBox.selectedProperty()));
    timerLabel
        .textFillProperty()
        .bind(
            Bindings.when(timer.statusProperty().isEqualTo(CountdownTimer.Status.FINISHED))
                .then(Color.FIREBRICK)
                .otherwise(Color.FORESTGREEN));
  }

  private String formatTimeRemaining() {
    Duration d = Duration.ofMillis(timer.getTimeRemaining());
    if (showMillisBox.isSelected()) {
      return String.format("%02d:%02d:%03d", d.toMinutes(), d.toSecondsPart(), d.toMillisPart());
    }
    return String.format("%02d:%02d", d.toMinutes(), d.toSecondsPart());
  }

  @FXML
  private void handleStartOrResumeTimer(ActionEvent event) {
    event.consume();
    timer.start();
  }

  @FXML
  private void handlePauseTimer(ActionEvent event) {
    event.consume();
    timer.pause();
  }

  @FXML
  private void handleResetTimer(ActionEvent event) {
    event.consume();
    timer.stopAndReset();
  }
}
```

Main.java:

```java
package com.example;

import java.io.IOException;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException {
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/com/example/App.fxml"));
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
    primaryStage.setTitle("Countdown Timer Example");
    primaryStage.show();
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Slaw 

Thank you so much for this elaborate solution/explanation. Life has been busy, but I plan to try this out and work with it. Will update when possible.

Comment: Sure thing. Let me know if there's any problems with the above.

Comment: Hi @Slaw I keep getting a `NullPointerException` when I run the program that points to this line in `Main.java`: 

`Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/App.fxml"));`

I appended the package to the line to get this:
 
`Parent Root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/package/App.fxml"));`

That results in a `ClassNotFoundException`.

Nor can I open `App.fxml` in SceneBuilder.

Do you have any suggestions? I can't seem to get the program running. I'm using Java 8 and NetBeans btw. Thanks.

Comment: Hmm. When posting here I omitted my package structure and it seems FXML does not like that. If you move all the code into a package, add the necessary package statements, and alter the imports/`fx:controller` in the FXML file it seems to work.

Comment: I edited the code to make everything be in a package named `com.example`, including the FXML file. However, while the code now runs (tested from the command line) it appears Scene Builder still can't open the file.

Comment: Okay, I'll give it a try. Thanks.

Comment: If you look at my answer's [edit history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61333413/revisions) you can see what I changed.

Comment: Great, that seemed to work. I'll play around with this code some more now that it can run.